# 2004 Ford Explorer accelerates too quickly from idle

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, acceleration, explorer

I have a 2004 Explorer/v8/4wd/bauer edition.  When I take off from a stop, there is a slight lag and then the vehicle over accelerates (sort of "jumps" off the line).  If I gradually apply the accelerator, get the vehicle rolling slightly (maybe 5mph), it seems to do this less but it is still very touchy the first say 5-10% of the throttle from start. I took it to the transmission shop, he says it is not the transmission (he has seen the same issue with another explorer - he thinks it's the throttle control mechanism).  The vehicle runs and shifts perfectly at all speeds, conditions, other than starting from a stop.

Comment: Whens the last time you had the upper intake tract cleaned, to include Idle Air Control Valve and throttle plate?

Comment: Just purchased vehicle so I do not have that info.  Mileage is 155K.  Looking through service records and I don't that that has ever been done.

Comment: That is where I'd start. I am a fan of a good [SeaFoam treatment](http://ls1tech.com/forums/general-maintenance-repairs/534376-how-seafoam-your-car.html) and then using some carb cleaner to clean up the throttle body and IAC.

Comment: @paulster2: thanks for the seafoam writeup.  I might buy the throttle plate and ACV being my issue, but not going for the internal carbon buildup or dirty crankcase... That's a stretch that I can't see a connection to.

Comment: The idea of the SeaFoam write-up is about getting the *entire* engine clean. You are right in that internal carbon buildup or a dirty crankcase (if you keep your oil changed on time especially) is not going to be a real issue. Get the top end cleaned up and I'll bet your issues will be gone. That part of the procedure is what I was really getting at.

Answer (score 1):

I removed and cleaned the air control valve thoroughly and the problem is completely gone.  I tried using seafoam for the cleaner and while it did work, it was not nearly effective as choke and carb cleaner (suggested by someone else on the Ford forum).